# Is it possible to embed SWF in mobile application with PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, flash

Is it possible to embed SWF animation in PhoneGap application?

Answer (score 1):

Flash doesn't run on iOS devices, so the answer is no. Technically you could use Flex Mobile, but, that's not what you are asking here.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I want to animate a sequence of png in my phonegap application. I tried to use jQuey and setInterval function but I want an other way to do that because I have many animations based on image sequence.